# Method expecting list when I use List<string>

Tags: c#

I'm currently using ASP.NET Core 6 and C#, and I want to return string and a list of string from my method, so I try this:

```
public async Task<(string, List<string>)> Save(IFormFileCollection files)
{
    var fileNames = new List<string>();

    return isUploaded ? ("Ok", fileNames)
                      : ("Look like the image couldn't upload to the storage", fileNames);
}
```

But I get this error:

[image]

Why is it expecting a string if I define a `string` and a `List<string>`?

Comment: What is `IBlobHelper`?

Comment: Well it looks like you're implementing an interface that declares that `Save` needs to return just a `Task<string>`. You can't change the return type of a method when implementing an interface.

Comment: You are not returning tasks. Just to check it works try to wrap both values in `Task.FromResult()`

Comment: @Leron That's not necessary. The compiler does that automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens because you have declared the class to implement an interface `IBlobHelper` which includes the `Save` method. The `Save` method declared in the interface returns a `Task<string>`.

Either you have to change the declaration of the `Save` method in the interface `IBlobHelper` or add a second `Save` method to your class that corresponds to the method in the interface.

Comment: This, and as a side note: Returning an error as part of the return values (in a tuple in this case) is generally not considered best practice. Think about using Exceptions or other means of error handling.

Comment: @SebastianGrunow Exceptions generally shouldn't be used for normal control flow - they're for exceptional circumstances. See [discussion here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why).

Comment: Failure to upload a file is an exceptional cicrumstance

Comment: @NineBerry It's returning whether the file is uploaded or not. That doesn't necessarily mean it failed to upload. It might just mean uploading hasn't been attempted yet. We wouldn't know that without more context.

Comment: And, if you're dealing with a bunch of files and one of them fails for some reason and throws an exception, but the others proceed - that would get pretty messy. It really depends on the application requirements, but perhaps reporting the number of successful/failed uploads back to the user and letting them decide how to proceed is appropriate. It's something anticipated in the design, therefore not exceptional. Log the individual exception when it fails, but no need to propagate the exception back up the call stack to the user - users don't need to see exception details.

Comment: @mason I totally agree regarding the not-exceptional circumstances and that's why I put in "other means of error handling". Hard-coded error messages hidden somewhere in a service is also not a good idea. And you are right, without further context we cannot tell what the proper action to take would be. Anyhow, and that's a very personal thing, I'm not a fan of multiple return values - especially when they are tuples. Because that is also very hard to read. An out parameter with the failed files might be a good way. In any case that was just a side note and is not related to the question.

Comment: @SebastianGrunow True, using an exceptions vs returning a Tuple vs returning a hypothetical FileUploadResult object is very much a design decision that we don't have to make here, it'd be a more appropriate discussion elsewhere. I think we can all agree NineBerry's answer is the correct fix for the specific problem in the question, and that's what's really important here.

Comment: So you consider it is better to using something like `(await Task.FromResult("Ok"),fileNames)`? @SebastianGrunow